# Translating Python to C++, is it correct to return a new instance from a member function?

Tags: python, c++, oop

In Python3, I have a class `Resistor` with a method `series(self, other)` that returns a new `Resistor` instance with resistance equal to the series resistance of self and other.

```
class Resistor(object):
# a class to model a resistor 
    def __init__(self, res=0) :
        # default is "typical" value
        self.resistance = res
        return
    def series(self, other) :
    # Returns a Resistor object with resistance equal to self + other
        sum = self.resistance + other.resistance
        return Resistor(sum)
```

This works and seems to be an idiom in Python since variables are references to objects. The analogy is the Python string concatenation where the operation `newstr = str1 + str2` produces a new string object `newstr`.

If I translate literally into C++, this works:

```
class Resistor
{
  public:
    // data members
    double resistance;

    // member functions
    Resistor( double res = 1000.0);
    Resistor series(Resistor other);
};

Resistor::Resistor(double res)
{
    resistance = res;
}

Resistor Resistor::series(Resistor other)
{
    Resistor r = Resistor( resistance + other.resistance);
    return r;
}
```

And finally my questions... Am I safe with this literal translation? What happens to the new `Resistor` instance when the local variable `r` goes out of scope? Am I creating a memory leak? Should I be using pointers (which I know from C to be treacherous) ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Quick note. Using `sum` shadows the built-in sum. You should change that to something that won't clash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not creating a memory leak since your `Resistor::series` function will create a copy of `Resistor` object upon returning and will destroy the existing object (unless optimized by the compiler which in your case will most likely happen).

If this class was big/complex enough then copying at each call would certainly be inefficient. However the only thing your class has is a `double` field which (depending on the arch) might be of the same size as a pointer. So (even if copy optimization won't kick in) switching to pointers might not give you anything except for potential memory leaks. Exactly the other way around, huh? :)

However if the class is actually bigger then you should consider using pointers. Copying around big objects (which will eventually happen) is not really what you want. But when exactly should that happen? This is a very subtle problem and you won't get a straight answer. You can try different ways and do couple of tests to be sure.

*Side note*: passing arguments to a function by value copies it as well. But unlike the previous case this time the compiler **is not** allowed to optimize it unless it is a temporal. Thus consider passing by reference:

```
Resistor series(Resistor &other);
```

Comment: I agree with the side note, and if I develop the class to become a better representation of a real world resistor (tolerance, power rating, colour bands, etc.) i.e. more complicated, it would make sense to send just the references/pointers back and forth. I'm just not comfortable enough with pointers and references in C++ yet -- perhaps Python lulled me into a false sense of security.

Comment: @LouisB. Yeah, Python does lots of neat stuff behind the scene. Most importantly proper memory management. But you do have some nice features in modern C++ as well, e.g. shared pointers and many many more. Still the difficulty is few levels above Python unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with this.

Additionally, if you're interested in truly converting this code to C++-style, rather than just implementing a direct translation, consider defining an `operator+()`, instead of the `series()` method.

Your method returns `r`. The local variable `r` gets copied to wherever the return value goes, in the caller, before the variable goes out of scope and gets destroyed.

C++ compilers are allowed to eliminate the redundant copy here, and most of them, in fact, do -- essentially constructing `r` as the actual return value from this method, in the caller's context. But you do not need to worry about that.

Comment: Re: operator+()... Yes, that's where I was going. In Python I had `def __add__(self, other):` but I wanted to narrow down the scope of the question. Thanks.

Comment: I suggest against overloading `operator+` in `Resistor` class. Resistors are not mathematical objects, and can be "added" in series or parallel, each yielding different results. Thus, `operator+` is confusing.

Comment: @el.pescado Good point but in electronics, the + is reserved for series whereas two pipe bars || or two slashes // are used for parallel. In Python3 it was easy to do because all I needed to do was overload (more like hijack) the floor division operator // .